# How to access the contents of folder created on Google colaboratory system?

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, google-colaboratory

I want to access the contents of folder that I have cloned on the colaboratory system.

When I say !cd drive to get access of folder named 'drive', it gives the same answer upon !ls

pls help.

**Screenshot**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `!cd drive`. Use this instead

```
%cd drive
```